# Oracle Pivot: from rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, procedure

Hello is it possible to turn row values into columns.
I am using ORACLE SQL and I want to take the month and turn it into columns with the kpi value as shown below.
I tried partitions and merge statements but nothing seems to work.
I would really appreciate some help.
Thank you in advance.

Input data:

| department | year | month | kpi | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | 1 | sales | 5000 |
| A | 2000 | 1 | revenue per client | 120 |
| A | 2000 | 2 | sales | 6000 |
| A | 2000 | 2 | revenue per client | 140 |

Desired Output:

| department | year | kpi | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | sales | 5000 | 6000 |
| A | 2000 | revenue per client | 120 | 140 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pivot` to do so:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable (department varchar(20),year int,month int,kpi varchar(50),value int);

 insert into mytable values('A',    2000,   1,  'sales' ,5000);
 insert into mytable values('A',    2000,   1,  'revenue per client',   120); 
 insert into mytable values('A',    2000,   2,  'sales' ,6000);
 insert into mytable values('A',    2000,   2,  'revenue per client',   140);
```

Query:

```
 select * from (
 select department,year,month,kpi,value
 from mytable
 )
 pivot
 (
     max(value)
     for month  in (1,2)
 )
```

Output:

| DEPARTMENT | YEAR | KPI | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | revenue per client | 120 | 140 |
| A | 2000 | sales | 5000 | 6000 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac353742b6a5729110e5952a16e51502)*

Comment: Please share the table structures here? or if that is already another question then the link.

Comment: I fixed the second question already, thank you.

Comment: That's great. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggrwegation:

```
select department, year, kpi,
       max(case when month = 1 then value end) as month_1,
       max(case when month = 2 then value end) as month_2
from t
group by department, year, kpi;
```